# FBProphet giving error when growth='logistic' python

Tags: python, python-2.7, facebook-prophet

Here is the code data and the error that I am facing while using Fbprophet library in python.

**DATA**

```
   Timestamp     Open     High      Low        y    Volume  \
0  1519084800  11379.2  11388.9  11379.2  11388.9  0.083001   
1  1519084860  11362.0  11362.0  11362.0  11362.0  0.017628   
2  1519084920  11383.9  11395.0  11370.7  11393.0  3.023621   
3  1519084980  11384.3  11399.0  11379.9  11387.3  2.979175   
4  1519085040  11395.0  11400.0  11390.1  11390.1  1.430360   

                    ds   y_orig    y_pred  
0  2018-02-20 00:00:00  11388.9  9.340394  
1  2018-02-20 00:01:00  11362.0  9.338030  
2  2018-02-20 00:02:00  11393.0  9.340754  
3  2018-02-20 00:03:00  11387.3  9.340254  
4  2018-02-20 00:04:00  11390.1  9.340500
```

**Code:**

```
model = Prophet(growth='logistic')
model.fit(data);

#create 12 months of future data
future_data = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq = 'M')

#forecast the data for future data
forecast_data = model.predict(future_data)
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-c41038b3c799> in <module>()
      1 model = Prophet(growth='logistic')
----> 2 model.fit(data);
      3 
      4 #create 12 months of future data
      5 future_data = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq = 'M')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.pyc in fit(self, df, **kwargs)
    776         self.history_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['ds']).sort_values()
    777 
--> 778         history = self.setup_dataframe(history, initialize_scales=True)
    779         self.history = history
    780         self.set_auto_seasonalities()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fbprophet/forecaster.pyc in setup_dataframe(self, df, initialize_scales)
    242             df['floor'] = 0
    243         if self.growth == 'logistic':
--> 244             assert 'cap' in df
    245             df['cap_scaled'] = (df['cap'] - df['floor']) / self.y_scale
    246 

AssertionError:
```

Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: The error/traceback seems incomplete. Also the code is incomplete, no chance of reproducing your issue.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel No I got this much only on my jupyter notebook, let me share the screen shot with you: https://ibb.co/dwDdFx

Comment: The first issue, but I cannot be sure since you don't show a MCVE, is that your `data` dataframe has more columns than the `ds` and `Y` required.

Comment: @IgnacioVergaraKausel Strange to my knowledge .... the column have any effect on the dataframe...  What else information you were in need my friend.. I have provided the stuff Here .... If you need anything else then let me know....

Comment: I already said what it's missing, this is not a MCVE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should read the documentation for implementing the `growth='logistic'`. Here read the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/saturating_forecasts.html).

Now regarding your issue. I guess it can be resolved if you just make or add the dataframe as `cap and floor` column. Check this out:

```
#considreing your dataframe
df = pandas.read_csv('yourCSV')
cap = df['High']
flr = df['Low']
df['cap'] = cap
df['floor'] = flr
model = Prophet(growth='logistic')
model.fit(data);

#create 12 months of future data
future_data = model.make_future_dataframe(periods=1, freq = 'M')
forecast_data['cap'] = cap
forecast_data['floor'] = flr
#forecast the data for future data
forecast_data = model.predict(future_data)
```

I guess this will certainly help you.

Comment: One typo here, 'df = data'.

Comment: `floor` is optional and defaults to `0`

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use (periods=1, freq = 'Y') if you should create 12 month future data. not 'M'. if you want use 'M' change the periods to 12.